# How To rotate IP In Network Interface?

Tags: c#

I have VPS which supporting multiple ip addresses. I want to change those iP into network Interface in some intervals. So each request can send through unique IP. I have done code for fetching ip address list from server. but i have no idea that how can i rotate those i addresses in server.

Please suggest me that how can i set ip in network interface at runtime.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At first
HttpWebRequest has Proxy Property, see [HttpWebRequest.Proxy Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx)

At second you can try setting default proxy in config file like this

```
<system.net>
      <defaultProxy>
          <proxy
              usesystemdefaults="true"
              proxyaddress="<proxy server setting>"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```